# How to make conditional join between 3 tables

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure with a table variable as input:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IDArray] AS TABLE ([ID] INT NULL);
```

The procedure is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetFiltered](   
    @IDs as IDArray READONLY
)

AS
SELECT * FROM A JOIN (
    B JOIN @IDs ON B.BID = @IDs.ID
) ON A.AID = B.AID;
```

The `@IDs` parameter is used as a filter of B. My problem is that I want the procedure to return all records from `A` if `@IDs` is empty. I can't just do an outer join because that would make the filtering obsolete.

Sample Data:

```
Table A:
    AID | Name
    1   | X
    2   | Y
    3   | Z

Table B:
    BID | AID
    1   | 1
    2   | 1
    3   | 2
    4   | 2
```

Call to procedure with filter (Should return values of A with ID 1):

```
DECLARE @IDs IDArray;
INSERT INTO @IDs([ID]) VALUES (1)
Execute GetFiltered @IDS
```

Call to procedure without filter (Should return all values of A):

```
DECLARE @IDs IDArray;
Execute GetFiltered @IDS
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN won't work??

Comment: @RyanWilson No because I need the filtering to work in the case where IDs is not empty

Comment: please provide sample data

Comment: That is weird SQL syntax...

Comment: @MarianNasry I have added some sample data. Hope it makes it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I came up with an answer now. It can be solved by a left outer. Then I just need to check for null on the joined table, and only allow it to be null if a filter is not set.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetFiltered](   
    @IDs as IDArray READONLY
)

AS

DECLARE @Filtered bit;

IF Exists(SELECT * FROM @IDS)
    SET @Filtered = 1;
ELSE
    SET @Filtered = 0;

SELECT * FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    B JOIN @IDs ON B.BID = @IDs.ID
) ON A.AID = B.AID
WHERE Not B.AID IS NULL OR @Filtered = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use `exists` and `not exists`:
The `exists` part replaces the `join` between `B` and `@Ids`,
and the `not exists` part will return all rows if `@ids` contains no rows.

```
SELECT * 
FROM A 
JOIN B ON A.AID = B.AID
WHERE EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM @IDs ids
    WHERE ids.ID = B.BID
)
OR NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM @IDs
)
```

Comment: I think this is a solution, but it is a bit convoluted